# Sentence confusion

Tags: meaning, grammar

> The press more often **than** not focuses on animals well-known.

this sentence is so tricky that I do not understand why the word "than" stand in this position. And the meaning make me confused too.

Comment: I assume your sentence is incomplete - it isn't particularly common to phrase things '... animals well-known'.  It should be: 'The press more often than not focuses on well-known animals'.

Comment: 'More often than not' is an idiom meaning strictly 'on over 50% of occasions' but pragmatically used, like 'most often', for percentages round about 70-80.

Answer (score 2):

> the press more often than not focuses on animals well-known

Replace "more often than not" with the word "usually" and you'll get the meaning.

It'll then be

> the press usually focuses on animals well-known

Read more on [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/more_often_than_not).

Or, as Hank suggests, you could also rearrange "well-known" this way

> the press usually focuses on well-known animals

Comment: Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/more_often_than_not

Comment: Or "the press usually focuses on well-known animals"